# convert array of objects in to single string and push it in to same array

Tags: angular, typescript

I have Array Format show below:-

```js
questionValue = {
  others: [{
      inputValue: [{
        FormTypeValueArrayValue: [
          {
            form_type_value: "a"
          }, {
            form_type_value: "b"
          }, {
            form_type_value: "c"
          }, {
            form_type_value: "d"
          }
        ]
      }]

    },
    {
      inputValue: [{
        FormTypeValueArrayValue: [
          {
            form_type_value: "a"
          }, {
            form_type_value: "b"
          }, {
            form_type_value: "c"
          }, {
            form_type_value: "d"
          }
        ]
      }]
    }
  ]
}
```

But the required format in this type: -

```js
questionLevel = {
  others: [{
    question: "",
    form_type_value: "a,b,c"
  } {
    question: "",
    form_type_value: "d,e,f"
  }],
}
```

i have array which keeps repeating, so in every array i need form_type_value  in simple string but in respected array

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: do i need to send the whole code, because values i am getting are in dynamic

Comment: not whole code just how you get the data

Comment: questionValue = {
others: [{
  inputValue: [{
    FormTypeValueArrayValue: [{
      {form_type_value: "a"}
      {form_type_value: "b"}
      {form_type_value: "c"}
      {form_type_value: "d"}
    }]
  }]
  queValidtionsValue: 2
  value: "question title"
},
{
  inputValue: [{
    FormTypeValueArrayValue: [{
      {form_type_value: "a"}
      {form_type_value: "b"}
      {form_type_value: "c"}
      {form_type_value: "d"}
    }]
  }]
  queValidtionsValue: 2
  value: "question title"
}]
}

Comment: is this ok for you if you use for loop?

Comment: YOu can check the format now,

Comment: can't it be done with out loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
questionLevel.others = questionLevel.others.map((other)=>{
   other.form_type_value = other.formTypeValuesForEachQuestion
     .map( value => value.form_type_value).join(',');
   delete other.formTypeValuesForEachQuestion;
   return other;
});
```

you could try this

Comment: but the delete function is deleting the input box,  the formTypeValueForQuestion is array in which i am inserting the input box along with values

Comment: If you need the formTypeValueForQuestion property in the new array you can remove the delete statement from the code or assign the mapped value to a new array

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution:                                                   Note that you don't want loops but there are loops inside the function calls, it's just that you don't see them. They are at the language level. These solutions are called functional.

```js
var questionValue = {
  others: [{
      inputValue: [{
        FormTypeValueArrayValue: [
          {
            form_type_value: "a"
          }, {
            form_type_value: "b"
          }, {
            form_type_value: "c"
          }, {
            form_type_value: "d"
          }
        ]
      }]

    },
    {
      inputValue: [{
        FormTypeValueArrayValue: [
          {
            form_type_value: "a"
          }, {
            form_type_value: "b"
          }, {
            form_type_value: "c"
          }, {
            form_type_value: "d"
          }
        ]
      }]
    }
  ]
}


var questionLevel = {};
questionLevel.others = questionValue.others.map((v) => {
                return { question: "", form_type_value: v.inputValue.map(innerValue => 
                innerValue.
                FormTypeValueArrayValue.map
                (obj => obj.form_type_value).join(','))};
});

console.log(questionLevel);
```